# Microsoft Entity Framework is not saving changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, factory

Im currently trying to implement CRUD functionality with a dbfactory and generics with microsoft EF, but while listing entries is working, making changes to the db is currently not working.

```
 public class AbstractDataModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid gid { get; set; }
    }
```

Model

```
class SalesOrder : AbstractDataModel
{
    public int salesOrderID { get; set; }
    public int productID { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public Guid createdBy { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated { get; set; }
    public string orderDate { get; set; }
    public string orderStatus { get; set; }
    public string dateModified { get; set; }
}
```

A DBCore with some other functionality besides the ones listed here, which are not relevant for the factory

```
 public class DBCore : DbContext
    {
    public static string connectionString = "myConnectionStringToDb";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
```

Data Service which calls factory

```
class SalesOrderService : DBCore
{
    public DbSet<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }

    public OkObjectResult GetAllSalesOrders()
    {
        DBFactory factory = new DBFactory();
        return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(factory.GetAll(SalesOrders)));
    }

    public OkObjectResult AddSalesOrder(SalesOrder order)
    {
        order.gid = Guid.NewGuid();
        return DBFactory.AddOne(order);
    }
    public OkObjectResult UpdateSalesOrder(SalesOrder order)
    {
        return DBFactory.UpdateOne(order);
    }
    public OkObjectResult DeleteSalesOrder(SalesOrder order)
    {
        return DBFactory.DeleteOne(order);
    }    
}
```

simple CRUD-Factory,

```
       class DBFactory : DBCore
{
    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }

    public List<T> GetAll<T>(DbSet<T> dbset) where T : class
    {
        using (this)
        {
            return dbset.ToList();
        }
    }
    public static OkObjectResult AddOne<T>(T data)
    {
        using (DBFactory factory = new DBFactory())
        {
            factory.Add(data);
            factory.SaveChanges();
            return new OkObjectResult("Entry was sucessfully added");
        }
    }
    public static OkObjectResult UpdateOne<T>(T data) 
    { 
        using (DBFactory factory = new DBFactory())
        {
            factory.Update(data);
            factory.SaveChanges();
            return new OkObjectResult("Entry was sucessfully updated");
        }
    }
    public static OkObjectResult DeleteOne<T>(T data)
    {
        using (DBFactory factory = new DBFactory())
        {
            factory.Attach(data);
            factory.Remove(data);
            factory.SaveChanges();
            return new OkObjectResult("Entry was sucessfully removed");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Following the advices i changed the code so it should SaveChanges for the Factory, which also contains the context as a property. But it still doesnt seem to work for all database operations except listing all entries

Editv2: Thanks for the adivces it seems i have solved that problem, but a new one appeared :D
I can now do database operations like deleting entries, but now i cant list the entries anymore because the following error occurs, although the code there didnt really change:

*"Executed 'GetAllOrders' (Failed, Id=5fb95793-572a-4545-ac15-76dffaa7a0cf, Duration=74ms)
[2020-10-23T14:33:43.711] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetAllOrders. Newtonsoft.Json: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Context' with type 'FicoTestApp.Models.SalesOrder'. Path '[0].ChangeTracker'."*

Comment: you using thisw "DBfactory", but you're not using it. In my recollection, you shoul be `using` the context, and use context.SaveChanges. Anyway, you are doing changes on context, and then you try to call save on the other dbFactory object. EDIT: I got confused by names... the "context" in your functions is actually the DbSet for a particular table... But the idea is the same: you are changing some table and trying to save in another context where nothing has changed there (the new dbFactory thing)

Comment: You do 'db.SaveChanges' but adding entity to another set (context.Add(data))

Comment: you're giving your method a dbset of a context _a_, then create a second context _b_ with your dbfactory. _how_ should context b know about the changes you did in context a? also: this whole code just screams "overengineering"

Comment: thank you for your fast replies :D I think im understanding now where things go wrong, but how can i save the changes to the context of the DBSet im making there? because if i try context.SaveChanges() it tells me (of course) that the function doesnt exist, because its a DBSet and not a DBContext

Comment: Seems you have put so many abstractions that you got lost in them. I'd start with removing that factory, or if you insist - at least pass DbCore instance to factory constructor and do not inherit factory from DbCore.

Comment: There is no GetAllOrders method in the above code, but it sounds like you are somehow serializing the whole DbContext

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

to your

> startup.cs

it should to the job